# If a Grassmann number can represent a fermionic wave function, how does it represent the w.f. amplitude in space, and maybe time too?

Tags: wavefunction, grassmann-numbers

There's a clear account in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number of how Grassmann numbers $z$ can be used to represent fermionic wave functions, constructed from the exterior algebra $Λ(v)$ of the vector space $v$ of anticommuting grassmann variables $\{\theta_i\}$ that encode the Pauli Exclusion Principle of antisymmetry under particle exchange $\theta_i\theta_j=-\theta_j\theta_i$.

$$z = c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_k}c_{i_1i_2\cdots i_k}\theta_{i_1}\theta_{i_2}\cdots\theta_{i_k}$$

But where/how does the Grassmann number represent the space and maybe time-dependence of the wave function's amplitude?

An answer elementary enough for a chemist would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for tidying the maths expressions, Thomas.

Comment: The $c$’s can be functions of position and time.

Comment: @Ghoster That's helpful. Can you elaborate a little on that, please? How might the c's be arrived at? Is there a general procedure?

Comment: I’m not particularly familiar with the superspace formalism, but, if you are doing, say, non-relativistic quantum mechanics in superspace then the $c$ functions would be determined by the Schrodinger equation. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1933) is an example, although they don’t express the final result as this kind of expansion. Also, their notation for the fermionic dimensions is different but equivalent.

Comment: Their equivalent expansion is eqn. (2). See how the $f$’s are functions of the commuting coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to get the idea from the paper and the fs. A 1D Schrodinger equantion with a delta potential makes sense to me so I'll try to work my way through the maths.